# Still no space after removing files

Tags: 10.04, server

I've deleted lots of large files with `rm` and still `df` shows no space.

On `/dev/sda1` which is 2TB SATA hdd, **after deletion** I have

```
3.6MB    .Trash-0
1.5T     downloads
16K      lost+found
```

But `df` shows

```
/dev/sda1 Used: 1.7T   Avail:17G
```

So how to really purge deleted files?

Comment: Are you using `df -h` or `df -H` to report free space? you may be seeing the difference between reporting using 1000 vs 1024 bytes per "kb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some application was holding them. After killing the application I was able to see the actual free space.